# How to change default sound input?

Tags: sound

Does anyone know a fix for [this](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-sound/issues/149) issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out pavucontrol.

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining how to automatically shift to headset mic when connected using pavucontrol ?